remove pipe and double quote in a string
im having some challenges in 1 CSV files im trying to decode.
as a delimiter i have pipe to identified column numbers and double quote to identify big string column.
I need to do prep processing script to remove this unwanted chars and for the sample2 add the missing double quote.
sample 1|Pending|"XXX LPA. LTD. - GridBird TEST (Monthly) (Collage Maker | Photo Editor)"|749|...
sample 2|Pending|"Take Five Entertainment" Limited Liability Partnership - Pack with cats "Halloween" (Cat Simulator: My Pets)|...

desire output:
sample 1|Pending|"XXX LPA. LTD. - GridBird TEST (Monthly) (Collage Maker Photo Editor)"|749|...
sample 2|Pending|"Take Five Entertainment Limited Liability Partnership - Pack with cats Halloween (Cat Simulator: My Pets)"|749|...

im trying to regex to identify the first sample and replace with sed but it seems im missing some sed behavior how it works as first i need to identify the string pattern and then replace only that chars in this case any | or "
^.*\|\".*(\||\").*(\"\|\d|\|\d)

on this regex I'm identifying the string between |" and ("|digits or just |digits).
Next step is what I'm confused how to do with Sed.
Best Regards
Solution for this based on new samples i got. Thank you @Ed Morton
awk '
    {
        {
                gsub(/\{/, " ");
                gsub(/\}/, " ");

        # First split the record on `"`s and replace every `|` (plus
        # any surrounding spaces) inside a quoted field with a blank.
        FS=OFS="\""; $0=$0
        for ( i=2; i<=NF; i+=2 ) {
            #print $i
            gsub(/[[:space:]][|][[:space:]]*/, " ", $i)
        }

        FS=OFS="\""; $0=$0
        for ( i=2; i<=NF; i+=2 ) {
            #print $i
            if ($i ~ /[#\-\+\?A-Za-z][|][#\-\+\?A-Za-z]*/)
            {
            #print $i
            sub(/[|]{1}/, " ", $i)  
            }
        }


        # Now split on `|`s, remove `"`s within fields and
        # add `"`s around every field that contained `"`s
        FS=OFS="|"; $0=$0;
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            gsub(/"/, "", $i);
        }

        print
    }


The quoted fields don't contain any | so you could just strip all the " of the file

@Fravadona sample 1 in the question contains "XXX LPA. LTD. - GridBird TEST (Monthly) (Collage Maker | Photo Editor)", note the | inside the quotes,

@maciera your input is not valid CSV as a field in a CSV cannot contain multiple sets of quoted strings as in your Sample 2, that may be why you're struggling to work with it. Can you change whatever is producing these files to produce valid CSV?

Regarding \d - there is no standard POSIX tool, including awk and sed, that will recognize \d as meaning [0-9] so dont use it unless you're using some tool that supports PCREs, e.g. perl, python, ruby, or GNU grep -P.

Are you sure you want the output you show for sample 2 instead of sample 2|Pending|"""Take Five Entertainment"" Limited Liability Partnership - Pack with cats ""Halloween"" (Cat Simulator: My Pets)"|... or similar which would also be valid CSV but not lose the "s within the field?

Here's one way to get the output you provided from the sample input you provided using any POSIX awk:
$ awk '
    {
        # First split the record on `"`s and replace every `|` (plus
        # any surrounding spaces) inside a quoted field with a blank.
        FS=OFS="\""; $0=$0
        for ( i=2; i<=NF; i+=2 ) {
            gsub(/[[:space:]]*[|][[:space:]]*/, " ", $i)
        }

        # Now split on `|`s, remove `"`s within fields and
        # add `"`s around every field that contained `"`s
        FS=OFS="|"; $0=$0;
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            if ( gsub(/"/, "", $i) ) {
                $i = "\"" $i "\""
            }
        }

        print
    }
' file
sample 1|Pending|"XXX LPA. LTD. - GridBird TEST (Monthly) (Collage Maker Photo Editor)"|749|...
sample 2|Pending|"Take Five Entertainment Limited Liability Partnership - Pack with cats Halloween (Cat Simulator: My Pets)"|...


thank you for your solution. I have to make some changes on it:

I would harness GNU AWK for | removal following way, let file.txt content be
...|Pending|"XXX LPA. LTD. - GridBird TEST (Monthly) (Collage Maker | Photo Editor)"|749|...

then
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""}{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2){gsub(/[|][[:space:]]*/,"",$i)};print}' file.txt

gives output
...|Pending|"XXX LPA. LTD. - GridBird TEST (Monthly) (Collage Maker Photo Editor)"|749|...

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that " is both field separator (FS) and output field separator (OFS) then use for loop to remove | in even field (i.e. inside quotes) after doing that I print changed line.
Regarding 2nd requirements you would need to determine which columns count as big string column then you might do following, let say you want adjust quotes in 3rd column of |-sheared file.txt content be
1|shortstring|"correctly quoted string"
2|shortstring|"this" need better "quoting"
3|shortstring|quotes are missing

then
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{gsub(/"/,"",$3);$3="\"" $3 "\"";print}' file.txt

gives output
1|shortstring|"correctly quoted string"
2|shortstring|"this need better quoting"
3|shortstring|"quotes are missing"

Explanation: I use gsub to replace " using empty strings (i.e. remove them) from 3rd field, then change 3rd field to concatenation of quote with 3rd with quote, after doing that I print line.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.3.1)

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -E ':a;s/^([^"]*("[^"|]*"[^"]*)*"[^"|]*)\|/\1/;ta
        s/[^|]+/\n&\n/3
        h
        s/.*\n(.*)\n.*/\1/
        s/"//g
        s/.*/"&"/
        G
        s/(.*)\n(.*)\n.*\n/\2\1/' file

Firstly, identify any |'s between double quotes and remove them. This might be an iterative process.
Delimit the 3rd field and surround it by newlines.
Make a copy of the current line.
Remove all but the 3rd field.
Remove all double quotes.
Surround the 3rd field by double quotes.
Append the copy of the original line.
Overwrite the original 3rd field with the amend one.
